# iOS | Swift | Hiding other views when selecting top menu option

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit

I currently have 6 views in one view controller with a button to select which view to show and hide.

```
@IBOutlet weak var liveScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var sevenDayCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var fourTeenDayCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var thirtyCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var ninetyCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var allDataCollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Using the button, I control the selectedIndex, and the selectedIndex hides and shows.

```swift
var selectedIndex = 0 {
        didSet {
            switch selectedIndex {
            case 0:
                liveScrollView.isHidden = false
                sevenDayCollectionView.isHidden = true
                fourTeenDayCollectionView.isHidden = true
                thirtyCollectionView.isHidden = true
                ninetyCollectionView.isHidden = true
                allDataCollectionView.isHidden = true
            case 1:
                liveScrollView.isHidden = true
                sevenDayCollectionView.isHidden = false
                fourTeenDayCollectionView.isHidden = true
                thirtyCollectionView.isHidden = true
                ninetyCollectionView.isHidden = true
                allDataCollectionView.isHidden = true
            case 2:
                liveScrollView.isHidden = true
                sevenDayCollectionView.isHidden = true
                fourTeenDayCollectionView.isHidden = false
                thirtyCollectionView.isHidden = true
                ninetyCollectionView.isHidden = true
                allDataCollectionView.isHidden = true
            case 3:
                liveScrollView.isHidden = true
                sevenDayCollectionView.isHidden = true
                fourTeenDayCollectionView.isHidden = true
                thirtyCollectionView.isHidden = false
                ninetyCollectionView.isHidden = true
                allDataCollectionView.isHidden = true
            case 4:
                liveScrollView.isHidden = true
                sevenDayCollectionView.isHidden = true
                fourTeenDayCollectionView.isHidden = true
                thirtyCollectionView.isHidden = true
                ninetyCollectionView.isHidden = false
                allDataCollectionView.isHidden = true
            case 5:
                liveScrollView.isHidden = true
                sevenDayCollectionView.isHidden = true
                fourTeenDayCollectionView.isHidden = true
                thirtyCollectionView.isHidden = true
                ninetyCollectionView.isHidden = true
                allDataCollectionView.isHidden = false
            default:
                break
            }
        }
```

This seems like a very long way, is there any better way of doing this?

All I can think of is having all of the views in one scrollView and scrolling the content as the user changes the selectedIndex. Would that be the only and the best way to solve this?

Comment: Hide All six views before Switch and remove ishidden = true lines of code from all cases

Comment: Why have 5 separate collection views? Why not just one? Just adjust the data array depending on the selected index.

Comment: @HangarRash How haven't I thought of that. That is how I solved the problem and works like charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various ways to write that - here's one:

```
var selectedIndex = 0 {
    didSet {
        let views: [UIView] = [
            liveScrollView, sevenDayCollectionView,
            fourTeenDayCollectionView, thirtyCollectionView,
            ninetyCollectionView, allDataCollectionView,
        ]
        for (i, v) in views.enumerated() {
            v.isHidden = i != selectedIndex
        }
    }
}
```

You might even put that array at the class-level:

```
let views: [UIView] = [
    liveScrollView, sevenDayCollectionView,
    fourTeenDayCollectionView, thirtyCollectionView,
    ninetyCollectionView, allDataCollectionView,
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // normal stuff
}
```

and then shorten `didSet` to:

```
var selectedIndex = 0 {
    didSet {
        for (i, v) in views.enumerated() {
            v.isHidden = i != selectedIndex
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage of doing it that way is you may want to loop through that array of views elsewhere.